# Avoid looping through VBA arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Using the below code taken from (http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/PassingAndReturningArrays.htm) is there a way to avoid the looping in both functions:

```
Sub AAATest()
    Dim StaticArray(1 To 3) As Long
    Dim N As Long
    StaticArray(1) = 1
    StaticArray(2) = 2
    StaticArray(3) = 3
    PopulatePassedArray Arr:=StaticArray
    For N = LBound(StaticArray) To UBound(StaticArray)
        Debug.Print StaticArray(N)
    Next N
End Sub

Sub PopulatePassedArray(ByRef Arr() As Long)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' PopulatePassedArray
    ' This puts some values in Arr.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim N As Long
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(N) = N * 10
    Next N
End Sub
```

For Example I would like it to look something like this:

```
Sub AAATest()
    Dim StaticArray(1 To 3) As Long
    Dim N As Long
    StaticArray(1) = 1
    StaticArray(2) = 2
    StaticArray(3) = 3
    PopulatePassedArray Arr:=StaticArray
    Debug.Print StaticArray(:,1) 

End Sub

Sub PopulatePassedArray(ByRef Arr() As Long)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' PopulatePassedArray
    ' This puts some values in Arr.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim N As Long
        Arr = Arr * 10
End Sub
```

But obviously this latter code doesn't compile.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This sort of "removing loops" is typical of Matlab.. I don't think you can do a similar thing in VBA.

Comment: Sadly, there is no map-like function in VBA

Comment: VBA isn't very expressive. The only place you can "skip" loops is ranges, where you can apply a formula on a large range in one go. Languages like Matlab can work seamlessly with arrays and vectors, functional languages provide you with `map`, python has `map` and list comprehensions and the list goes on. In VBA, we are stuck with looping.

Comment: What is the bigger problem you're trying to solve. Is there a speed issue? The thing I'd find most cumbersome is the initial population of the array. BTW, your example is slightly off. The individual repopulations should be `Arr(N) = Arr(N) * 10`.

Comment: If you want to write code using "map" - type functions then you could always write a few small functions to provide that functionality.

Comment: When you say "avoid looping", realize that even with things like Python's Map and Reduce functions, looping takes place, you just don't see it happening. It is entirely possible to implement something that hides loops in VBA when applying a calculation to an array, but since VBA doesn't support functions as First Class objects (and therefore definitely not lambda functions), you would have to use Classes and Interfaces to acheive the same thing.  If you want, I can provide an example.

Comment: @Blackhawk, excellent point about looping behind the scenes in other programs. I'd argue it's an advantage in VBA that you can do it explicitly, allowing one to define functions and classes that do exactly what you want.